# Clarify my UML diagram

Tags: uml

I am learning objects orinted and Java due to a change in job role and found a good book on both.  My first exercise produces this UML diagram but could someone clarify if the part circled in red is correct please?  For me Milk is a sub class of Beveredge but still should have some association with Dairy.  I am using a free UML tool called "Dia"

[image: First UML Exercise]

Answer (score 0):

this is normally where you start working with interfaces.

if you have an interface LivingThing  with eat() and drink() and possibly slurp()
then your classes can implement interfaces Edible or Drinkable (or maybe Slurpable)
and you could replace Food and Beverage with them.

Then your subclassing depends on what interactions you want to be possible.
In some languages you can also work with Multi Inheritance instead.